# scoping in many_to_many associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this relationsship

```
class House
 has_many :apartments
end 

class Apartments
 belongs_to :house
 has_many :category_join_table
 has_many :categories, :through => :category_join_table
end
```

I made a scope method in my house model with the purpose "show only houses with apartments"

```
scope :with_apartments, lambda { joins(:appartments).group('appartments.id').uniq { |h| h[:id] }}
```

So i can make a house.with_apartments in controller logic. This works fine so i get only the houses with apartments on the page. And the houses without apartments on not showed.

But now i want make a association to my categories model (many_to_many). So "show only house with apartments and category = X"

Comment: To clarify your question: you are trying to achieve the following flexibility: `@some_category.houses`?

Comment: yes. with the house association. On my template page if got this -     @houses.each do |house| 
- house.appartments.each do |a|
#{a.guests}

Comment: You can join multiple associations like this, joins(:appartments => :categories), then append some queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# in category.rb

has_many :category_join_table
has_many :apartments, :through => :category_join_table
has_many :houses, :through => :apartments
```

Comment: thanks Jdoe. Can you help me how i write the scope method based on you're relations.

Comment: To do what? Because your question was: "show only house with apartments and category = X". To do this use: `Category.find(some_id).houses`.

Comment: i tried this..scope :with_appartments_and_agri, lambda { joins(:appartments).group('appartments.id').uniq { |h| h[:id] } joins(:appartments => :categories).where("categories.name = 'Agriturismo'")}}

but i did not work...

Comment: jdoe...almost working...but when there are 2 apartemts in the same categorie (apartment with pool in this case) and the appartments belong to the same house. The house is rendered 2 times....how can i fix this?

Comment: jdoe...thanks! one final thing...the case is..there is house A, with apartments..a-1, a-2, a-3. apartment a-2 is only with a pool. At this point when i do Category.find(pool).houses.uniq all the apartments are show...and not only a-2. Do you also have a solutions for this..issue? many thanks!!

Comment: You said: *when i do Category.find(pool).houses.uniq all the apartments are show* -- this makes no sense since this query returns houses, not apartments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10313/discussion-between-user874862-and-jdoe)